# Why does Anniyan read "Sarvadharmaan parityajya" before killing?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, anniyan

*[Anniyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniyan)* (2005) is a Tamil movie which was dubbed into Telugu as *Aparichitudu* and *Aparichit* in Hindi. It is based on [split personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder). Vikram plays three characters Ambi, Remo and Anniyan (Aparichitudu and Aparichit in Telugu and Hindi respectively).

Due to frustration caused due to public negligence, Ambi develops two other personalities without his knowledge. Anniyan decides to punish criminals, irresponsible and lazy citizens as they are punished in [Naraka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka) i.e., Hindu equivalent of hell. He starts punishing such people when they come across him according to punishments laid down in Garuda Purana.  Every time he sentences punishment i.e., killing he says a verse from the [Bhagavad Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita). Bhagavad Gita is a dialogue between Krishna and Arjuna. Quoting from [holy-bhagavad-gita.org](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/66):

> sarvadharmānparityajya māmekaṃ śaraṇaṃ vraja |
>   ahaṃ tvāṃ sarvapāpebhyo mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śuca:  || Bhagavad Gita 18.66||
>
> Translation : Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

Why does Anniyan say this shloka/verse before killing the criminals or sinners?

Comment: is this one similar to Glass trilogy? (Glass, Split etc..)? About the phrases this character saying, it could be simply because it may help him/her to justify his/her actions and he's following a code, he may trust that what he do is holy, removing sinners from their sins and from the world, thus make it a better place.

Comment: @Vishwa Yes, the character's justification is cleaning the world by removing them from this world and making the society a better place. He follows Hindu way of punishing as followed in hell. But my question is why this special verse. How is it related to what he is doing? Originally, it is a verse from a Holy scripture which is a dialogue between Krishna and Arjuna.

Comment: Sorry bruv, can't help you with this movie since I haven't watched it. but it could be similar to general idea on what these characters do, what they based it on, their code and stuff... About the given phrase, isn't it kind of simplify and justify what he doing? He offer them peace without fear and request them to surrender peacefully to it, for a greater good.

Answer (score 2):

The personality of Remo is born because of his inability to be impressive. His suppressed nature triggers an alternate persona who's a lady's man and is able to easy charm the heroine.

The Anniyan personality is because of the unjust corruption he experiences in his past which cost the life of his sister. The Anniyan personality believes that he is the one who will cleanse the world off evil. Anyone who commits a crime is a sinner and deserves to be punished.

The shloka is because:
By killing the sinner he's liberating the world from the sinner, and is also liberating the sinner from life so that he can sin no more.